# Can't execute query on geocoding service

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, geocoding, arcgis

I'm building Flex 3 application and I have a geocoding service (http://.../GeocodeServer) on a ArcGIS server (ESRI). I'm trying to execute a query on this service in order to retrieve some

informations.

Unfortunately, when I execute the query, I get this error : *[RPC Fault faultString="" faultCode="400" faultDetail="Invalid URL"]*

It's definitely not the URL that is invalid since my locator uses it without any problem.
What could possibly the cause of this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer after all.

Esri GeoCoding services aren't able to answer queries.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing against the URL using something like CURL or even in your browser. Please make sure those work first.